# How to add controls in the tab item programmatically in wpf with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a tab control and Created the tabItems dynamically, but i dont know how to add controls into the tabItems using MVVM. Could any one help me

Comment: What do you mean under "add controls into the tabItems using MVVM"? Do you need to add some controls there? Are controls on each tab similar (not content)?

Comment: I need to add some controls into the tabPage dynamically using mvvm

Comment: @Tanya My solution should allow you to do exactly that. Add a comment if you have any questions. :)

Comment: It's not quite right to tell that we are going to dynamically add items to `View` using `MVVM`. Google it: [Dynamically adding UserControls WPF](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dynamically+adding+user+Controls+WPF). There are a lot of answers.

Comment: addin controls dynamically has nothing do to with mvvm. can you specify your needs? if you want a tabpage look different in dependence of the datacontext(viewmodel/viewmodel property), you just have to use datatemplates

Answer (score 19):

There are a few ways to programmatically add Tab Items in `WPF` and I am going to show you a simple example on how I deal with this in my application.

First I host a collection of the `ViewModels` for the `TabItems` (or `Workspaces` as I refer to them) in my `MainWindowViewModel.cs`:

```
private ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> _workspaces;

public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
{
    get
    {
        if (_workspaces == null)
        {
            _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
        }
        return _workspaces;
    }
}
```

Next I add a reference to the various controls in my `MainWindow.xaml`. This is important as we want to make sure that whenever the collection contains a `ViewModel` that it displays the appropriate `View` for that Model.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyUserControlViewModel}">
            <vw:MyUserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
```

If you have multiple types of UserControls you simply add them all here like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstUserControlViewModel}">
            <vw:FirstUserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SecondUserControlViewModel}">
            <vw:SecondUserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ThirdUserControlViewModel}">
            <vw:ThirdUserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Next we add the `TabControl` and bind it to our `Workspace` Collection.

```
 <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"/>
```

Then I simply add my `ViewModels` to the Collection to have them show up in the `TabControl`.

```
Workspaces.Add(new FirstUserControlViewModel());
Workspaces.Add(new SecondUserControlViewModel());
Workspaces.Add(new ThirdUserControlViewModel());
```

My `WorkspaceViewModel` that I base the `TabItem` collection of is very simple and looks something like this:

```
public abstract class WorkspaceViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public String HeaderText { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
           return HeaderText;
    }
}
```

**Adding a TabItem:**

To create a `TabItem` you simply create a `UserControl` and `ViewModel` like you normally would using WPF and the MVVM pattern.

```
namespace MyApplication.ViewModel
{
    public class FirstUserControlViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
    {
        public FirstUserControlViewModel ()
        {
            base.HeaderText = "My First Tab";
        }
    }
}
```

Next you need to bind a `View` to your new `ViewModel`.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstUserControlViewModel }">
        <vw:FirstUserControlView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then you create an instance of the `ViewModel` and add it to the collection in your `MainWindowViewModel`.

```
FirstUserControlViewModel firstvm = new FirstUserControlViewModel();
Workspaces.Add(firstvm);
```

And now the `TabItem` should show up in your `TabControl`.

**Loading TabItems dynamically using Extensions:**

In some cases you might even need to load `TabItems` from plugins dynamically without the host application first knowing about the `TabItem`. In these cases you need to have the plugin register the `View` and `ViewModel` with the application domain.

This is very easy to do, and actually something I do for one of my `MEF` based projects. I have an post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204614/load-wpf-ui-into-mvvm-application-from-plug-in-assembly/12204789#12204789), with some additional details as well.

All you need to do is add a `Resource Dictionary` to your plugin/extension and make sure that the host application loads it once the plugin has been imported.

To show you a fast example I would have a `View.xaml` in my extensions:

```
   <ResourceDictionary
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MyExtension.Test">

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vw:TestViewModel}">
            <vw:TestView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

I then expose the ResourceDictinary using MEF to the Host like this:

```
private ResourceDictionary _viewDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

public ResourceDictionary Dict
{
    get
    {
        return _viewDictionary;
    }
}

_viewDictionary.Source =
                new Uri("/MyExtension.Test;component/View.xaml",
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Last you use `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add` to load the View.xaml into the host.

Answer (score 5):

You Dont have to add controls you just have to specify the UserControl.

TabControl has two properties `ItemTemplate` && `Content Template`

ItemTemplate is for how the `Tab` will look where as

ContentTemplate is how the Tab Content will Look... so...

## Xaml for the above

```
            <TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabList}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTab,
                                               Mode=TwoWay}"
                 <!--This is How tab will look-->                                   >
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="20"
                                   Height="20"
                                   Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                   Source="Images\TreeView\yourFavImg.png" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=TabText}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!--This will be the content for the tab control-->
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                <!--This User Control will contain the controls you like-->
                        <ViewLayer:YourFavUserControl />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add components in the data Template

Comment: What exaclty you want to do.... Add controls to a userControl.... DataTemplate fill the `<ViewLayer:YourFavUserControl />` withy data required. be specific in telling the requirement... and elobrate in your question

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to add controls if you use mvvm. you just have to create datatemplates for your viewmodel objects you wanna display.

all you need is a contentcontrol/presenter which is bind to your viewmodel and the datatemplate will show what you want.